# Adding UITableViewControllers tableview to new UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple question.

I have a normal UITableViewController displaying a UITableView. When the user taps a button in the top right corner of my application I want the TableView to flip from right to left and then display a new UIView. I've found the animation UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight which flips the current view and replaces it with a new one. However, the animation involves removing the current view from its superview and then adding the new view to the same superview.
The problem is that when I am trying to do this in my UITableViewController class i only have one view - the UITableView - which I need to remove. When the UITableView has been removed I have no view left to add my new view to, and the screen goes blank.

My idea of getting around this problem is to create a UIView and put the UITableView in that view. I would the in the animation remove the UITableView from the UIView and then add my new view to the same UIView.
Something like this when initializing:

```
superViewTest = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
[superViewTest addSubview:self.tableView];
```

And then like this when animating the flip:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
[superViewTest addSubview:self.mapView];
```

Or does the UITableView in the UITableViewController already have a superview I'm not aware of?

I wish I could have explained this better, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you use a standard UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController. Then you can control, directly, both the table and its parent view. Add the table as a subview of the UIViewController's view, and swap it with your flipside view the way you described.

Comment: Yep, you do not need a UITableViewController for a table view. It does some stuff that isn't that useful if you're using a table view defined in a nib. Just make sure you declare UIViewController as implementing the table view protocols.

Comment: Well, ok. But if I use a UIViewController and implement the <UITableViewDelegate> protocol, will my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method still be invoked? I'm not using a nib to create the UITableView...
Thanks again!

Comment: Just make sure that you set your table's delegate and datasource to point to your viewController, and they'll all be called as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You may just be able to use presentModalView or whatever. Create a new app with the "Utility" project template and look at how it does this. The modal view stuff won't work though if you don't actually want to switch to a modal view.